# ubuntu 12.10 not working after Upgrade from 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-12.10, ubuntu-unity

after upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 i have a black screen, don't see any thing 
I well remove this version and install a new one .
but I need My all projects from  local host. it's Important .

Comment: Perhaps better to try and ask on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: **Don't panic!**

You can always download a *live image* in order to recover all of your files. Various Linux distributions are available as a *live image*, including Ubuntu. These *live images* allow you to try out a Linux distribution without installing anything on your hard drive, which can be a great tool for data recovery.

There's a bunch of ways to get a live image bootable on your USB flash drive.

Depending on the operating system you have available, these ways vary. Fortunately, Ubuntu's official website provides well-documented tutorials for

**[Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)**,

**[Mac OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)** and (somewhat ironically)

**[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)**.

Comment: if I have a live image, cane access for my recent projects ?

Comment: Yes, you can. With a live image, you can access the *file system* on your hard drive and rescue everything you need.

Comment: thanks Chiru for your help, i restored my projects now by live image.
but no way to fix the Ubuntu Linux System.